# How i can use async and await ? it's not Working

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Well, I have three functions i want the first function to be executed to get its ID and then the second  and third function could be executed, Here is an example :

```
  async persistAll()
{
  await (this.AddElement());
   this.AddElement2( this.Id);
   this.AddElement3( this.Id);
   
}
```

As i said i want the first one to finish first then the other functions could do their job, SetTimeOut is working fine but i don't wanna use it because it depends about how much data I would send.
here is an example of the AddElement function:

```
   async AddElement (){
       let a = 1,
       let b = 2
       id= a+b
      return new Promise(resolve => {id})
}
```

this is just an example for what I am trying to do, anyways it doesn't wait at all i tried this as well

```
Promise.resolve(id)
```

what i am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your AddElement function is not returning a `Promise<number>`, but instead, a `Promise<Promise<number>>`. This is because `async`/`await` are syntactic helpers; for async function, any value returned automatically gets wrapped inside a promise.

In your case, you can let typescript help you find the problem by explicitly annotating the return types. Write this instead, it should give you a compiler error:

```
async AddElement (): Promise<number>{
   let a = 1,
   let b = 2
   id= a+b
   return new Promise(resolve => {id})
}
```

To fix it, remove the `new Promise`, and just write

```
async AddElement(): Promise<number>{
   let a = 1;
   let b = 2;
   id= a+b;
   return id;
}
```

Here's a [TS playground with a working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOMC8MDeAUDCTAJIAmAXDAAwA0hxpSEAnmMDGnAE4QBLaAEEMGABQBKZiSKl5MKAAshAOkq4YSAO5IBsccrXCKFAKJYUcMFCmSA3DIVGIqk%20cvWoAJkMrXlA5O8i5uphZwVjYAzH5qgY7yAL6MTqwcXO4RUbaSNAAKvCAoQnAAPGAArigARnwAfHIKJFiwSJoAjInNMK0wNZre3c2gkLACFJpIANQ1wwqjECBYqhggAObiAERZnjZb9DATQT0wvHBQlbxgRxTzKUzyu5FevhM0VbV8kgTBpIvLOCrDbbZ45bwHW4nUgPJxgryxd4wT51Xg-JojcBLFZrTY7cJ7KDRSHHe6EJJMRCoTBAnj8IRQUQSSSqZTWcRSXD1GAAnEgrYAEXAcC2kiCQA). It produces this output:

```
[LOG]: "AddElement",  3
[LOG]: "AddElement2", 3
[LOG]: "AddElement3",  3
[LOG]: "Done"
```

For reference, here's the full code of that playground:

```
const example = {
    Id: 0,

    async persistAll()
    {
        this.Id = await (this.AddElement());
        this.AddElement2(this.Id);
        this.AddElement3(this.Id);
    },

    async AddElement(): Promise<number>{
        let a = 1;
        let b = 2;
        const id = a+b;
        console.log("AddElement", id);
        return id;
    },

    AddElement2(id: number) {
        console.log("AddElement2", id);
    },

    AddElement3(id: number) {
        console.log("AddElement3", id);
    }
}

example.persistAll().then(() => console.log("Done"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it still not working i even added a console log after AddElement() but its starts with console log  directly ...

Comment: i want atleast the function to be 100% executed then pass to the second function

Comment: I copied the code I suggested to a typescript playground and edited this into my original answer. There must be a detail in your code that is missing in your original question. Can you post a minimal way to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for this:

```
async persistAll(){
 this.id = await this.addElement();
 this.AddElement2( this.Id);
 this.AddElement3( this.Id);
}

async AddElement (){
       let a = 1,
       let b = 2
       id= a+b
      return new Promise(resolve => {id})
}
```

It would be very helpful to have a sandbox or more code to get a better understanding of what you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i did the same thing but it is still not working ...

Comment: i want atleast the function to be 100% executed then pass to the second function

Comment: You don’t need to use async in AddElement here at all, since it will the work the same way u excepted.